# Postgres, select all records from table A and left join with possible existing records of B on condition?

Tags: postgresql

I have a `device` table, and a `user_device_details` table.
There can be multiple `user_device_details` for one `device` record.

I want to get a few devices (usually around 3) by device.id, and left join possible existing `user_device_details` records with it for a given `user_device_details.user_id`

So, give me all devices with id (23,4,10) and if you find a related `user_device_details` with `user_id`=87 join it so I can have the device and the possible `user_device_details` record generated by user 87.

I am not sure how I can return all three devices even if maybe only device 23 has a `user_device_details` record.

So, ALWAYS return all devices I pass ids in for, and if it has `user_device_details` from a specific user_id then also put that next to the device row result (join?).

I tried something like this:

```
select *
from device d
left join device_details dd on d.id = dd.device_id
where d.id in (23,4,10)
and dd.user_id=${userId}
```

When I run this, I only get device 23 because it's the only one that has `user_device_details.user_id`=87.

How do I get all three devices together with the two null `user_device_details` for devices 4 and 10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition `where.dd_user_id = ..` turns your left join into an inner join as it will remove all rows that did not have a match for the join condition.

You probably want:

```
select *
from device d
  left join device_details dd 
         on d.id = dd.device_id
        and dd.user_id=${userId}
where d.id in (23,4,10)
```